# Magento : Fatal error: Call to a member function getMethodInstance() on a non-object

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework, magento-1.7

Login Admin > sales > orders  and I click view   some order show detail but some order  show error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getMethodInstance() on a
>   non-object in
>   /home/easter13/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/View.php
>   on line 96

help me please, And thank you.

[image]

Comment: What's line 96?

Comment: Well, [it's not core code!](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.7/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/View.php#L96) - bad! **Do not modify core code!!!!!**

Answer (score -1):

This is happning because there is a problem with your mail configuration. I have 2 suggestions:

1. Open `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/View.php` 
at line number 92 replace your code with below code:

```
if ($this->_isAllowedAction('emails') && !$order->isCanceled()) {
    $confirmationMessage = $coreHelper->jsQuoteEscape(
        Mage::helper('sales')->__('Are you sure you want to send order email to customer?')
    );
    $this->addButton('send_notification', array(
        'label'     => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Send Email'),
        'onclick'   => "confirmSetLocation('{$confirmationMessage}', '{$this->getEmailUrl()}')",
    ));
}
```

Then clear your cache, refresh the page and see if your error is gone.

2. Open `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/View.php`
at line number 92, uncomment this code and then clear your cache,
refresh the page and check whether your error is gone.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This is a bad answer, because you should never encourage developers to override core Magento code. Also, your #2 point doesn't seem to make sense in the context of #1.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But i do with your suggestions 1 and 2 but it not working. What do you think problem other for this error. Thank you verry much

Comment: @RobbieAverill Can i get help https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/319888/57334 thanks